# Is there an equivalent of GeoDjango for Flask or other Python web frameworks?

Tags: python, geodjango, development, framework, flask

I have experimented with GeoDjango, but I think nobody would be surprised if I said there's quite a steep learning curve. I prefer Flask, which I also know much more than Django anyway, but I couldn't find anything like GeoDjango for Flask. Is there any such package around that I might have missed?

Comment: What sort of mapping tasks are you hoping to do?  Simply displaying features?  Allowing users to query for features?  Buffer / intersect / other geoprocessing tasks?  Create new data?

Comment: Queries, intersection and geoprocessing tasks for sure, creating new data and altering existing data is also necessary.

Answer (score 7):

There is [GeoAlchemy2](https://geoalchemy-2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), a spatial extention to SQLAlchemy which does similar things as GeoDjango.